# nodejs request module parse body

Tags: node.js, request

I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var request = require('request');

app.use(myMiddleware);
app.listen(5010);

var payload = { id: 1 };

request({
  method: 'POST',
  body:JSON.stringify(payload),
  url: 'http://localhost:5000'
}, function(err, res, body) {
  console.info("Request Done");
})
```

In my middleware code I want to parse the body and extract the request id, yet for some reason the following code doesn't work (payload is undefined):

```
  var myMiddleware= function (req, res, next){
  var payload = req.body;
  if (payload.id === 1) console.info("first request!!!!!");
  next();
}
```

When I try to print "payload" all I get is `[object Object]`.

Could you please tell me how to extract the id, and how to print the attributes of the payload object?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Is `request` from node's own http library or are you using some external lib?

Comment: have you tried payload = JSON.parse(req.body); It's a string after all.

Comment: @jsalonen I'm using request from express

Comment: @Patrick yes, I did, it gives me the famous "unexpected token" error, which means that the data I pass is not in the correct format.

Comment: You really need to be more specific here: can you provide me with actual `require` line from which you get the request object. Right now I can think of at least 3 possible request objects you could be using here -- and your current syntax even mixes two of them.

Comment: @jsalonen I've added the missing code (sorry I didn't do it to begin with). Thanks :) I'm using request from //github.com/mikeal/request.git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by adding:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

and by adding the following to the request code:

```
json: true
```

After adding the json=true attribute I also removed JSON.stringify(...) from the body of the request (now I don't need to stringify the body since it expects a json object)

Thanks.